# What SE site should I post my GPGPU physical simulation questions to?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've asked a question regarding [particle simulation acceleration structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646131/nearest-neighbors-in-cuda-particles) on SE, yet the question doesn't seem to get much attention (at this time only 36 views – and quite frankly I doubt starting bounty would get me any further with this number of views so far).

It seems to me that SO is not especially good place for algorithm-oriented kind of questions. What is the most appropriate StackExchange site to ask this kind of questions?

I'd also appreciate your suggestion of ex-SE sites and forums where my question would get better chance of being answered.

Comment: Interesting... Your algorithm question there is nearly closed (4 CVs) as "unclear what you're asking". In this case, I'm thinking it's the heavy science and math that seems to be necessary to solve the problem. In order to reach the broadest audience, the problem should require as little domain-specific knowledge as possible to read/answer.

Comment: @Laurel The core of the question is how to find (all 27) near neighbors for a point in a 3D grid using Z-index curve, which doesn't require any physics knowledge per-se. I'm afraid I cannot simplify the question more (I've tried to provide details and some code). Would the question be a good suit for [cs.se]? What's your opinion?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe [Sci Comp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (not the same site, despite similar names), which seems to be more accepting of code than Comp Sci.

Comment: @Laurel Perfect! Thank you for your answer. I'm going to post a simplified version of my question there.

Comment: Tell me how it goes!

Comment: @Laurel I've finally posted the question. http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24582/nearest-neighbors-in-radius-via-z-order-order-curve